# Remove unwanted characters from Dataframe values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe full of locus/gen names from a multiple genome alignment.

However, I am trying to get only a full list of the locus/name without the coordinates.

```
    Tuberculosis_locus  Smagmatis_locus             H37RA_locus             Bovis_locus
0   0:Rv0001:1-1524     1:MSMEG_RS33460:6986600-6988114 2:MRA_RS00005:1-1524    3:BQ2027_RS00005:1-1524
1   0:Rv0002:2052-3260  1:MSMEG_RS00005:499-1692    2:MRA_RS00010:2052-3260 3:BQ2027_RS00010:2052-3260
2   0:Rv0003:3280-4437  1:MSMEG_RS00015:2624-3778   2:MRA_RS00015:3280-4437 3:BQ2027_RS00015:3280-4437
```

To avoid issues with empty cells, I am filling cells with 'N/A' and then striping the unwanted characters. But it's giving the same exact result, nothing seems to be happening.

```
for value in orthologs['Tuberculosis_locus']:
    orthologs['Tuberculosis_locus'] = orthologs['Tuberculosis_locus'].fillna("N/A")
    orthologs['Tuberculosis_locus'] = orthologs['Tuberculosis_locus'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('\d:').rstrip(':\d+'))
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? I'd like the following output:

```
Tuberculosis_locus  Smagmatis_locus  H37RA_locus  Bovis_locus
    0   Rv0001  MSMEG_RS33460   MRA_RS00005 BQ2027_RS00005
    1   Rv0002  MSMEG_RS00005   MRA_RS00010 BQ2027_RS00010
    2   Rv0003  MSMEG_RS00015   MRA_RS00015 BQ2027_RS00015
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your desired output is?

Comment: Apologies! I've edited my original question with the table that I want. Basically remove anything before the first ":" and remove everything after the second ":". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by `:` with a maximum split of two and then take the 2nd elements, eg:

```
df.applymap(lambda v: v.split(':', 2)[1])
```

Comment: I have tried:orthologs = orthologs.fillna("N/A") and then orthologs.applymap(lambda x: x.split(':', 2)[1]) but it's giving me the error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Presumably you're getting an `IndexError` then @Harr1ls. `.fillna(':N/A)` instead so it's got at least one colon

Comment: Or change the lambda to be `lambda v: 'N/A' if pd.isna(v) else v.split(':', 2)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean(x):
    x = x.split(':')[1].strip()
    return x

orthologs = orthologs.applymap(clean)
```

should work.

Explanation:

`applymap` is for the whole dataframe and `apply` is for a data column.

`clean` is a function you want to apply to every entry of the dataframe. Note that you don't need `(x)` anymore when you use it together with `applymap` or `apply`.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: @Tyler2P Thank you. I've added explanations.